# Too many unwanted tasks done by vsphere.local\Administrator on Esxi host

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

We have too many tasks done by vsphere.local\administrator on some of our Esxi hosts (shown in vCenter monitoring).As we haven't done any of these tasks manually, I didn't find a key to the reason. The tasks are starting and stopping a service (the service is not clear), change lockdown mode and opening firewall ports. No further information shown.

[image]

Comment: These aren't normal - change the administrator PW asap, grab a VC log bundle and log a case

Comment: I agree. In the vCenter session list you can check what IP address this session is coming from and what type of client it is using.

Comment: By checking active sessions we found that tasks are done by Zerto.